# ViewPager and RecyclerView issue with fragment transition

Tags: android, android-jetpack, fragmentmanager, android-viewpager2

The setup is like so:

- Single activity app (MainActivity) with nav_graph
- HomeFragment has viewPager2 with 3 subfragments
- Each of these 3 fragments are same fragment with RecyclerView showing different list of posts
- User can click on a post and that navigates to completely new screen/fragment (Details)
- Clicking "Back" button throws exception:

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1790)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1826)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
  at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragme

So my feeling is that issue happens between ViewPager2 with RecyclerView and FragmentTransitions through navigation. Why? Well, clicking "back" arrow makes the transaction to 'home' screen, but also home screen having viewpager also deals with fragment transitions and this somehow creates the issue.

To give more context, this is how tabs/viewpager is set (in HomeFragment):

```
    val viewPager: ViewPager2 = container.findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
    viewPager.adapter = PagerAdapter(parentFragmentManager, lifecycle)

    val tabLayout: TabLayout = container.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
    val names = arrayOf("Najbolje", "Popularno", "Novo")

    TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position -> tab.text = names[position] }.attach()
```

Here's the adapter:

```
class PagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

private val fragments = listOf<Fragment>(
    MyListFragment.newInstance(Type.TOP),
    MyListFragment.newInstance(Type.POPULAR),
    MyListFragment.newInstance(Type.NEW)
)

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fragments.size
}

override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragments[position]
}


}
```

and here's the code for setting up recyclerview:

```
private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        val adapter = MyListAdapter(requireContext(), myService)

        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        viewModel.posts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { post -> adapter.submitList(posts.map { PostItem(it) }) }

        addScrollListener()
    }
```

One of the similar issues was somewhere solved by changing parentFragmentManager to childFragmentManager within setTabs method, but that creates another issue that throws exception among the lines of 'RecyclerView already has layoutManager set up'

Let me know if not enough information has been provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `FragmentManager` - for **every** fragment that is fully contained within the layout of another (such as your `ViewPager2` managed fragments), you **must** use `childFragmentManager` to properly nest the fragments.

```
viewPager.adapter = PagerAdapter(childFragmentManager, lifecycle)
```

This is required not only to restore your state properly (something which using the activity's `supportFragmentManager` will not do), but to ensure that the parent fragment goes through its state transitions first and only then does the child fragments go through their transitions, fixing the "already executing transactions" issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However after trying exactly this approach, I run into another issue, and that is:
After going back from details fragment back to the homefragment (with all the viewpager+recycler views) I get an exception while setting-up recyclerview's layout manager (here: `binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager`). Error being:
`LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@6f31cd1 is already attached to a RecyclerView`. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay I tried another thing and you tell me if it makes sense:
Since in my homefragment I used to keep the layoutmanager as a strong ref. field, by removing it and making new layout manager each time onCreateView is called it fixed the issue. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new your layout manager every time you move to `onCreateView`.

Comment: I got the error `LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@6f31cd1 is already attached to a RecyclerView` when I used `lazy` delegate in kotlin; avoid use it to instantiate adapters.

Answer (score 0):

It appears by trying out whole lot of different similar implementation so far I wasn't able to reproduce the issue after changing the "parentFragmentManager" into: activity?.supportFragmentManager